# Animation in Cocos2d from custom method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have animation layers stored within SpriteBuilder. I am calling it on a touch began method

**heroCharacter.m**

```
@implementation heroCharacter{
    CCNode *_heroNode;
    staminaNode *_staminaReference;
}
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

  //Play animation
            CCBAnimationManager* animationManager = _heroNode.userObject;
            [animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"ouch"];
}
```

**This works fine.**

I am then trying to call the animation in a custom method in another file but it then doesn't work. I have no idea why? **I have tested to make sure the method is called and it is.** but the actual animation isn't called. It is the same code as used in the `touchBegan`

```
-(void)sleepingHero {
 //Play animation
 CCBAnimationManager* animationManager = _heroNode.userObject;
 [animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"ouch"];
```

No Idea how to debug this.

My custom method is being called like this in another file. Called `bedroomScene`.:

```
@implementation .....{
    heroCharacter *heroHolder;
}
```

then in didload:

```
heroHolder = [[heroCharacter alloc] init];
```

then in another method:

```
[heroHolder sleepingHero];
```

Comment: check `animationManager` and `_heroNode`. is either nil?

Comment: they are nil. WHy would this be when it works with the same code in the touchbegan...

Comment: please, post the code where you are calling `sleepingHero`...

Comment: @sergio updated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By executing:

```
heroHolder = [[heroCharacter alloc] init];
```

in your other file, you are instantiating a new node that has no relationship whatsoever with the original `_heroNode` node in your first class.

What you should do is passing the actual `_heroNode` from your first class to your second class, so that you can reference it in the latter. There are multiple ways of doing it:

- you could define a property in your second class and set it from the first (supposing the first class instantiates the second);
- you could add an argument to your second class' initialization method and pass `_heroNode` in it;
- or, you could expose `_heroNode` in your first class through a property (or custom accessor method) and then pass a reference to the first class into your second class.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

you could try something like this (where you currently create your bedroomScene):

```
bedroomScene = [BedRoomScene scene];
bedroomScene.heroHolder = _heroNode;
```

For this you will need to make your `heroHolder` ivar into a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) CCNode* heroHolder;
```

(in your `BedRoomScene` interface or class extension).

Comment: it does help, now Im just trying to find a example about how to do the things you suggested :/

Comment: I would suggest adding a property to the second class and then, after you create it, you set this property to refer to `_heroNode`. If you post some more code, I may be able to be more detailed.

Comment: updated it with a small bit of code. Not sure what exactly you need. All relevant code to the methods has been added. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When is `sleepingHero` being called? If it is called before `didLoadFromCCB` is called it means that the code connections are not set up yet and you cannot reference anything created in SpriteBuilder.

Comment: Its called after the didLoadFromCCB method